# How to make child button affect parent value?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class parent():
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []
        self.value = 0

    def main(self):
        try:
            self.child.pack()
        except:
            None

class child(Button):
    def __init__(self,master,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(master,command = self.main,**kwargs)

    def main(self):
        #change parent value += 1

new_parent = parent()
new_parent.children.append(child(root,text = 'hello'))
new_parent.main()
root.mainloop()
```

There will be multiple children in parent.children and multiple parents. How do i make the child button affect parent value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a method on an object, you need a reference to that object. The simplest way is to pass a reference to the parent when creating the child. This has nothing to do with tkinter, it's a fundamental aspect of programming.

```
...
class child(Button):
    def __init__(self, master, parent, **kwargs):
        self.parent = parent
        super().__init__(master,command = self.main,**kwargs)

    def main(self):
        self.parent.value += 1

new_parent = parent()
new_parent.children.append(child(root, new_parent, text = 'hello'))
...
```